# Why doesn't the Variadic Template Function inside a while loop print to the console?

Tags: c++, while-loop, c++17, variadic-functions

I want to try the flag-controlled while-loop statement that prints a statement and accept user input using variadic template function? Is this possible?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... _args> void write(_args && ...args) { ((std::cout << args), ...); }

template<typename... __args> void read(__args && ...args) { ((std::cin >> args), ...); }

auto main() -> int {

    int a;

    while(a > 100) {
        write("Enter a number: ");
        read(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: `a` is not initialized before the loop starts. Your code has [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, the variable `a` is not initialized. Hence, the variable contains a garbage value, so it will result into a runtime error.

Therefore first initialize the variable, then run a `while` loop on it.
And the code need to take the user input using `variadic` template function. So you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... _args> void write(_args && ...args) { ((std::cout << args), ...); }

template<typename... __args> void read(__args && ...args) { ((std::cin >> args), ...); }

auto main() -> int {

    int a;

    // To initialize a
    write("Enter a number: ");
    read(a);
    while(a > 100) {
        write("Enter a number: ");
        read(a);
    }
}
```

If `do-while` loops are allowed, then the below is also a possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... _args> void write(_args && ...args) { ((std::cout << args), ...); }
template<typename... __args> void read(__args && ...args) { ((std::cin >> args), ...); }

auto main() -> int {

    int a;

    do {
        write("Enter a number: ");
        read(a);
    }while(a > 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
int a;
```

You declare `a`, but not initialize it, which means `a` is uninitialized and can hold some random value.

You can fix this problem by initializing `a` with a value bigger than 100, for example:

```cpp
int a = 101;
```

So your code should look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename... _args> void write(_args && ...args) { ((std::cout << args), ...); }

template<typename... __args> void read(__args && ...args) { ((std::cin >> args), ...); }

auto main() -> int {

    int a = 101;

    while(a > 100) {
        write("Enter a number: ");
        read(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I'm really new to C++ language and I wanted the output to be like this 
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

auto main -> int {
  int number;

  while(number>100) {
  cout << "Input number: ";
  cin >> number;
  }
  return 0;
}

Comment: @GilRovero I'm not really sure that I understand you, can you tell it with more details?

Comment: What I would like to happen is by using the Variadic Template Function inside the while-loop statement, sorry about my English

Comment: @GilRovero: your variadic part is ok. your issue is in the missing initialization.